# Locking boxes in place CSS

Tags: css, position, css-position

I have a website I'm building, and have a bit of positioning problem. I have two main text boxes on the content section, one to the top left and one to the bottom right. However, when the browser edges are moved in, th boxes move to the bottom box being on the left and the top box being on the right, as I'm using position:absolute. I was wondering if there was anyway to lock them in place, or to set a 'wall' in the middle where they couldn't be pushed past.

```
    #contentleft {
font: normal 14px verdana, sans-serif;
width: 450px;height:275px;
overflow-wrap:normal;
word-wrap:break-word;
position:absolute;
left:550px;
top:175px;
}
#contentright {
font: normal 14px verdana, sans-serif;
margin:0 auto;width: 500px;height:275px;
overflow-wrap:normal;
word-wrap:break-word;
position:absolute;
right:550px;
bottom:100px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `position:fixed` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the two textboxes are inside a parent div, then don't overuse css positioning. 
Make `#contentleft {float: left}` 
to control the positioning. Do not use `position: absolute` because when the browser is unmaximized, it will go to a different position. Instead, use `position: relative` so that the positioning is only inside its parent div.